# How to concatenate columns from different rows using Group By

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to concatenate 3 columns from 3 different rows into one row grouping by ID

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3
5   NULL    Test2   NULL
5   Test1   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL    Test3
```

Make it into

```
ID  FinalColumn
5   Test1, Test2, Test3
```

Thanks!!!

p.s. Values do not have to be in any specific sequence. The result could also be Test2, Test3, Test1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(MAX(Col1),'') +','+ ISNULL(MAX(Col2),'') +','+ ISNULL(MAX(Col3),'') AS FinalColumn
FROM tbl
GROUP BY ID
```

EDIT: updated to account for the potential of `NULL` values in any (or all) fields: I'm probably overthinking this but it might help.  Code sample below with my thoughts, feel free to ignore if you know you don't have NULLs.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Col1 VARCHAR(20), Col2 VARCHAR(20), Col3 VARCHAR(20))
INSERT @tbl --(Col1, Col2, Col3)
values 
(NULL, NULL, NULL),
(NULL, '2', '3'),
('1', '2', '3'),
('4', '5', NULL),
('1', NULL, NULL);

SELECT  
    ID, 
    LEFT(
        ISNULL(MAX(Col1 + ','),'') + ISNULL(MAX(Col2 +','),'')+ ISNULL(MAX(Col3 + ','),''), 
        ISNULL(NULLIF(LEN(ISNULL(MAX(Col1 + ','),'') + ISNULL(MAX(Col2 +','),'')+ ISNULL(MAX(Col3 + ','),'')),0),1) -1
        ) AS FinalColumn
FROM @tbl
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Updated the query to correct a mistake in the GROUP BY, can you try again?

Comment: If any one of those values is ALL null, then concatinating null to string gives null.

Comment: Edited one more time, a suggested edit that I accepted actually changed the concatenation string.

Comment: I'm sure we overwrote one another.  I had rolled back that edit because it was nonsense.

Comment: Thanks! You learn something every day. DIdn't even know you can do a MAX on a varchar type. You rock!

Comment: That must have been it, @paqogomez.  Thanks for the help!  ssokol91, added in some extra NULL handling logic to account for the potential problems that paqogomez pointed out. Use it if you think you might return a NULL value in one or more of the columns: basically it moves the comma values to only be added if the value before them is NULL. The LEFT() function removes the last comma in the string (in case Col3 returns a NULL).

Comment: Thanks! I realized that I don't even need the comma to separate the values. Space was sufficient. Thanks again for the last update on the NULLs.